# Calculate the side of rectangle using only length, no area or perimeter

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

My geometry is a little rusty due to not doing it for so long. I  am trying to find the side of a rectangle by only knowing one sides length. Is this possible?

Length of one side is $0.21875$. I have gone about this using trig by dividing the rectangle into half creating two right angle triangles with theta thus equaling 45 degrees.

Is this the correct way of going about this?

Answers I get are:

$0.1350496052$ (Taking $0.21875$ as Opposite angle)

and

$0.354332582$ (Taking $0.21875$ as Adjacent angle)

Calculations:

$\tan(45) = \frac OA$

Thanks

Comment: If it is a rectangle divided into two equal halfs through a long diagonal, the angles would not be 45 degrees.

Comment: @Gordon why would they not be? To clarify I mean two equal triangle halves if that was not clear. All interior angles should add up to 360. Remainder after dividing into half would be 180 - right angle. Leaving 45 for the two remaining angles

Comment: Suppose a diagonal was drawn from the bottom left to the top right of the rectangle. Depending on how long the rectangle is, the angles may not be 45 degrees; they could be 50 and 40, 81 and 9, etc.

Comment: A consequence of @Gordon's comment is that it is impossible to compute the length of the other side without more information

Comment: @Patricio Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Gordon, when a rectangle is divided into two parts of equal area through a long diagonal, the angles would not be $45^{\circ}$

Construct a rectangle $ABCD$ and draw $BD.$ Now $\angle ABD=\angle BDC$ as they are alternate angles. If we assume (as you said) that $\angle ABD=\angle DBC=45^{\circ}$ then $\angle BDC$ must also be $45^{\circ}$ but then $\triangle BCD$ will become isosceles meaning $BC=DC$ but it cannot be true as in a rectangle length$\ne$breadth. So we proved that $\angle DBC$ is not $45^{\circ}$ hence we proved that diagonal does not divide $\angle B$ equally.

For your main question, we can't determine the breadth of a rectangle if we just know it's length. The information is insufficient.

Comment: It's been so long since I have had to do any of this I completely forgot about alternate angles and so forth. Makes sense.

How would I go about calculating the length then knowing only it has a right angle and one sides length? Alternatively I would be happy to figure this out on my own with just a nudge in the right direction where to learn to do this again. Thanks

Comment: @NotReallyOliverTwist you cannot evaluate the breadth of the rectangle if you just know the length...the information is insufficient..and welcome :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Would explain why I was struggling to find examples online.

Comment: @NotReallyOliverTwist you're struggling... that's a good thing..this means that you're actually trying to learn things...this happened with me also when I first learnt geometry.. it's undoubtedly tough (at least for me)....now if you want to generate some examples....draw two parallel lines at a distance of $3$cm and again draw two different parallel lines at a distance of $2$cm...but the lengths of all $4$ lines should be same ...say $5$cm...then join both lines by their end points one by one to get two quadrilaterals...both are rectangle of same length but of different breadth